# VB.Net Convert Date format from yy-mm-dd back to standart date format (dd.mm.yyyy)

Tags: vb.net

So I'm running in a bit of trouble. I'm trying to convert a date format of yy-mm-dd back to dd.mm.yyyy. I tried to do it with lookup but i can get how to get only the second entry of this.

```
Dim lookupDateYear = DateString.ToLookup(Function(l) If(Len(l) < 2, l, Mid(l, 1, 2)), Function(l) Split(l, "-", 3).first)
Dim lookupDateDay = DateString.ToLookup(Function(l) If(Len(l) < 2, l, Mid(l, 1, 2)), Function(l) Split(l, "-", 3).last)
```

Comment: Can't you parse the date string to a `Date` object and then use it's `ToString` to the format you need ? or use a Regex it'll be simpler than what tou're actually doing

Comment: Mmh. How exactly would you do that? I never really used that alot, how can I obtain the 3 seperate YY.MM.DD from that string? If i get to this point i can just reassebmle them the way i need it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely doing this the hard way. This should work *much* better:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yy-MM-dd", Nothing).ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Note that the `/` character in here is a *placeholder* for the Date Separator Character defined for the given culture (In this case, `Nothing` maps to your current default culture. The Invariant culture is also often useful). If the culture settings have defined `.` as the date separator, you'll see `.` instead of a `/` in the output. If you want a `.` regardless of the date separator character, just change that to use the `.` instead of `/` in the format string, or use a `CultureInfo`, `DateTimeFormatInfo`, or `IFormatProvider` object where `.` is the date separator character.

Depending on how you plan to use this, you may also do better just keeping the date object, instead of converting it back into a string after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

After second though the Regex option isn't valid because the initial string doesn't have the century of the year.
*We could probably use it with some conditional but that would be cumbersome and error-prone*

That leaves us with the DateTime thing :

- First we use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) (or DateTime.TryParseExact) to ... well parse the string into a `DateTime` object according to a given format
- Then we use [DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which expects the string format we want.

That leaves us with :

```
' CultureInfo requires an Imports of System.Globalization
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact (DateString, "yy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim result As String = dt.ToString ("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Comment: that actually leaves me with a System.FormatException, I found a solution to myself as well now, maybe not the prettiest but it does the job. If u got an idea better than that let me know :) I'm not satisfied with my approach

Comment: @Alex according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) if you have that exception it's either 1) you didn't put a format (unlikely) 2) the hour designator AM/PM isn't correct in respect to the input (seems unlikely too here) and 3) the input hasn't the format you gave (most likely this one). Without proper sample code to check things It'll be hard for anyone but you to go further

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest but it does the job

```
    Dim parts = DateString.Split(New Char() {"-"c})
    Dim Year As String = "20" & parts(0)
    Dim Month As String = parts(1)
    Dim Day As String = parts(2)
    Dim result As String = (Day & "." & Month & "." & Year)
```

If anyone has a smarter way to do this I'm looking forward to see that.